# MySQL not starting on Mac OSX Mountain Lion (no mysqld process running)

Tags: mysql, xampp, mamp

I'm really frustrated about a problem I have with MySQL on my Mac, it's been like two weeks since it just doesn't start, I even tried creating another user account in my mac, with the same results.

I'm sure it used to work a month ago, and not it won't start. I used to use MAMP for launching MySQL and recently it stopped working.

I ran the following commands with no results:

1. `sudo ps aux | grep mysql` # (got no processes running under the name of mysql or mysqld)
2. `lsof -i` # (no results)
3. `killall -9 mysqld` # still, MySQL not starting

I tried reinstalling MAMP (no luck) and installing XAMPP for Mac, with same result (Apache runs just fine, MySQL won't start).

There is no info within the mysql error logs.

Also I tried installing MySQL by using the MMV MySQL Script shown here: http://code.macminivault.com/

And got this error after the installation:

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Quetzalcoatl.local.pid). /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: line 362: pidof: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 58: SORRY, MySQL IS NOT RUNNING ... THERE MUST BE A PROBLEM: command not found

Quetzalcoatl:valkcrm ed$
```

Any help would be really appreciated.